# Create a map building with kinect

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, kinect, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I am using ubuntu 11.04, electric and kinect with openni.

I only study tutorials (http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials)

and openni_launch (http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch).

I'm still new to ROS.

I want to build 3D indoor map.

But I don't know what to do.

How to create maps using ROS and Kinect?

Can you teach method, tutorial, material etc. ?

please~~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38946/create-a-map-building-with-kinect/) by [hahaha](https://answers.ros.org/users/2764/hahaha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at [RGBDSLAM](http://ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam).

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1